# Error in MyFirstApp Android Coding tutorial " intent constructor undefined.

Tags: android, eclipse

After spending numerous hours reinstalling, checking work and starting from scratch I have yet to solve my problem while following the MyFirstApp Android Tutorial. I am working with Androids eclipse bundle to code it so support packages should all be installed correctly. My error occurs in the following code (errors from compiler commented next to the error)

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); // **Error"The constructor Intent(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment, Class<DisplayMessageActivity>) is undefined"**   
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);// **Error "edit_message cannot be resolved or is not a field"**
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. To my knowledge all the instructions from the tutorial have been copied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first error, you need to simply replace `this` with `getActivity()`, because `this` refers to your `PlaceholderFragment` instance, which is not a valid `Context`, but the containing `Activity` is.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

change to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Your second error could mean there is no id `edit_message` defined in your layouts, or it means you simply forgot to import your `R` class.

That being said: if you have to ask here for these errors, I strongly recommend you get a Java book before diving deeper into Android development.

Comment: How would I go about importing an R class? I have a basic knowledge of Java and I'm attempting to make a simple android app as a practical usage of Java for a computer science class. edit_message is defined as the id for EditText `<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"` and EditText is imported.

Comment: If your package name is the same as the package name of your Activity, you actually don't have to import R and there's a different error. If not, you need to add import your.package.name.R; at the top of your file

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this to `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`
In sendMessage method try use `getView().findViewByID()` instead of just findViewByID().

Comment: This allowed me to compile the app, however the app ended up crashing when I pressed the Send button.

Comment: In `onCreateView()` try assign `onClickListener` instead in XML file. Do get proper references to your button, after inflating layout do something like`Button btnSend = (Button) rootView.findViewByID(ID)` then assign on click to your button `btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)`

Comment: I got it working.  It turns out I didn't need to make the changes suggested by you.  I put the method in the wrong area of the java file.  Once I placed the method inside the MainActivity (non static) class, it compiled just fine out of the box and no longer threw exceptions during run time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another class, called `DisplayMessageActivity` first. You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

And for the second error, please check in your `fragment_main.xml` whether you have the necessary view or not. It should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The training tutorials from developer.android.com are progressive. Please continue to the next lessons after one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this` in  `Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);` by `getActivity()` method you will have something like that `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);`